# How to add a PW Gift Card to a Woocommerce Order request API?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, json

I've been trying to make an order with a Gift Card that I generated
with the PW Gift Card Pro plugin, on our staging website.

I'm able to get the GiftCard, to change it, to
deactivate and all that with the PW Gift Card API, but then I try to integrate with our
solution, through the Order API of WooCommerce and it doesnt work. All the orders are made with the full price and woocommerce just ignores the pw_gift_card field.

How should I proceed? How should be the gift card field on the Order API?
It is something like:

```
"line_items": [{...}],
"shipping": [{...}],
"pw_gift_card": {
"card_number": gift_card["code"],
"amount": gift_card["amount"],
}
```

How do i add it? I just need to add to the Order call and to woocommerce recognize it.

We have a custom solution that i cant add their cart plugin, but we do have a basic wordpress website running alongside our solution, that is not accessed by the customers, that has the woocommerce cart with the PW Gift Card installed and if i make an order there, it is successful.
The order is processed and in the response, the field **pw_gift_cards_redeemed** is populated with the card number and the amount, and the final price is with the discount.

All the rest of the system is working, all orders are made without issues, coupons work with no issues and all that.

I even tried to name the field differently, with instead of pw_gift_cards be gift_card, pw_woocommerce_gift_cards and nothing seemed to work it too.

Comment: Third party plugins are considered off topic here, sorry. You should try to talk to PW Gift Card support.

Comment: I tried, but they dont answer so i came here to see if anyone knew about this.
Its not a big problem on how to solve, i just need to know how is the field and i will be good to go

Comment: They seem quite active on the [free plugin support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/pw-woocommerce-gift-cards/) if you haven't asked there. But if you're a paying customer you should expect better. I'd mention that you're a customer in the post, and ask if there's somewhere else you should ask instead.

Comment: I don't think we can help with the REST API syntax though since that's a pro feature. You're more likely to find someone else with Pro in the support forum I think even if the authors don't reply.